# Windows PHP Sending Email Through External SMTP

Tags: php, windows, email, smtp

I'm trying to get an in-house bugtracking software up and running.  Most of them are written in PHP, which our live server isn't set up for, and the ASPX trackers I've found won't work either, because our live server is running decade-old installs of its server software and upgrading it breaks two other sites we host for clients.

So I've been turning an old rendering machine (Windows XP) into a intranet server I can throw in the basement.  I'd install Linux...if a) reinstalling an OS wasn't a full-day job and b) if anyone in the office was actually familiar with Linux

Anyway.  I've got WAMP installed and working just fine (one minor issue that the "put on/offline menu item doesn't work, but I can manually change the configs) and Mantis is set up and ready to go, except for one thing.

Mantis can't send emails.

I've tried literally a dozen different ways of doing things: using gmail, using our own relay server, using a "fake" sendmail thing, and various config options between Mantis, PHP, and sendmail.

Nothing works and I am given remarkably little feedback on where the operation is failing.

Is there something I'm missing?  I had one person suggest that I needed to install Window's SMTP service (I will need to dig up and/or burn a Windows XP disc).  Only one guide mentioned enabling PHP's OpenSSL (but didn't say if that needed to be configured or how).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it tuns out, my problem was resolved by simply *using a different relay server.*  For some reason Verizon decided to just "nope" without saying why (not that PHP gets much in the way of error messages with email anyway).

http://mandrill.com/ offers a free SMTP service (for the first 12,000 emails per month you send) and as soon as I started using it, bam, everything worked.

I didn't need sendmail (using PHP_SMTP not PHP_SENDMAIL or PHP_MAIL in my MantisBT options) although may be required for other people.

Answer (score 0):

You might use "fake sendmail".

Most people use this tool to write emails to disk for testing purposes, but
the tool allows forwarding of emails to your SMTP server.

1. Download: http://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/sendmail.zip
2. Configure fake sendmail in "sendmail.ini" to contain your SMTP credentials
3. test sendmail on the CLI and check your SMTP account for outgoing mails
4. Configure php.ini (directive "sendmail_path")

   - sendmail_path = "sendmail.exe -t"
5. test mail() function from a PHP script

Config Files:

**sendmail.ini**:

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=****@gmail.com
auth_password=*******
force_sender=****@gmail.com
```

**php.ini:**

```
sendmail_path = "\"C:\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Comment: That would be one of the things I've tried, even said so in my original question.  I'll try those logfile lines though, haven't seen those mentioned before.  Edit: those logs were already set and they do not appear anywhere.

Comment: Have you tested sendmail on the CLI? Please try `error_logfile = c:\sendmail\error.log`.

Comment: Ok, I went digging to figure out how to send emails through the CLI with sendmail, but it just hangs, as if I didn't give it enough or the right parameters.  I also changed the config error log location and tried some more, still no error log.

Comment: Ok, it hangs. That might indicate that there is some trouble connecting to gmail. Can you try "telnet smtp.gmail.com 25" and "telnet smtp.gmail.com 587" and see if you get a connection? (Leave telnet with "quit".) In others words, lets check that the ports can be opened/forwared and are not blocked by a firewall or router. And maybe try port "465".

Comment: Looks like the connection works on 587 and 465 (587 gives me some response text ("220 mx.google.com ESMTP r8sm11411855qah.8"), 465 does not).  Telnetting into verizon on 465 does the same thing as gmail on 465 (successful connection, no text displayed).